# multi tenancy with mongodb not updating version column of domain class

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement multi tenancy with mongodb using following gorm plugin:

```
'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.0.4'
```

The Domain classes which `implements MongoEntity<Book>, MultiTenant<Book>` correctly gets saved to the respective databases. However, in these domain classes version column is never saved. This means when I retrieve the same object and try to update some values, I get optimistic lock exception. Since version column is null and comparison fails.

This is how I am saving the object:

```
Tenants.withCurrent {
     book.save(flush: true)
}
```

I have pushed the sample code which reproduces the same scenario. I appreciate any help or pointer in the right direction.

[Sample code to reproduce scenario](https://github.com/z-j/grails-exp/tree/master/MongoMultiTenancyTest)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that your service is annotated with @Transactional.

This issue doesn't mention the same error as yours but does seem to indicate that multi tenancy and @Transactional may not play well together https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/767